# Weird behaviour of ternary Operator with cascade dart

Tags: dart, conditional-operator

Why do both of the results print the same?

```dart
final list1 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
final result1 = true ? list1 : list1..removeWhere((e) => e == "a");
print(result1); // prints ["b", "c"]

final list2 = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
final result2 = false ? list2 : list2..removeWhere((e) => e == "a");
print(result2); // prints ["b", "c"]
```

This happens only in ternary condition. When in normal if-else this works just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ternary operator is evaluated before the cascade operator, so basically the code is equivalent to

```dart
final result1 = (true ? list1 : list1)..removeWhere((e) => e == "a");
```

rather than what you might have expected

```dart
final result1 = true ? list1 : (list1..removeWhere((e) => e == "a"));
```

See: [Operator precedence](https://dart.dev/language/operators)

Comment: Intuitively, the cascade operator feels closer to the member access (dot) so I blindingly assumed its precedence to be higher than ternary (similar to dot) and stopped using my brain. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you put the code in an IDE with analyzer, you can see that the second `list1` is grayed out (dead code) but `..removeWhere` is not. That's where I realized

Comment: How did I miss this? This should have been an obvious giveaway. Guess there's always somethnig new to learn!

Answer (score 0):

because this code

```
true ? list1 : list1
```

return you a `list1`. then on this `list1` you call
`list1..removeWhere((e) => e == "a")`. the same story here:

```
false ? list2 : list2..removeWhere((e) => e == "a");
```

to check this you could wrap second part with round brackets:

```
final result1 = true ? list1 : (list1..removeWhere((e) => e == "a"));
```